# How do I set the column width when using pandas.DataFrame.to_html?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), but I am still confused about how I set the column width when using `pandas.DataFrame.to_html`.

```
import datetime
import pandas

data = {'Los Angles': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 20.5, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1517.1},
        'London': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 0, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1767.4},
        'Kansas City': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 10, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1.4}}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)

html = df.to_html()
```

The above code results in :
[image: df.to_html result]

How do I go about forcing the column width so that they are the same?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
import pandas

data = {'Los Angles': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 20.5, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1517.1},
        'London': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 0, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1767.4},
        'Kansas City': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 10, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1.4}}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 40)

html = df.to_html()
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, see if it works. Also you can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)

Comment: the `max_colwidth` property doesn't help to set the minimum column width, which is often an issue for columns that wrap around. Is there anyway to fix that? Thank you. I have read the link you have above and it doesn't address this at all.

Answer (score 4):

I find it better to use the set_table_attributes function.
You are then able to set e.g. a CSS-class to the table. In case you have many tables on your output it is much better readable.

```
import datetime
import pandas

data = {'Los Angles': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 20.5, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1517.1},
        'London': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 0, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1767.4},
        'Kansas City': {datetime.date(2018, 9, 24): 10, datetime.date(2018, 9, 25): 1.4}}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)

html = df.set_table_attributes('class="table-style"').to_html()
```

Your CSS could look something like that:

```
    .table-style {
                  width: 100%;
}

    .table-style td {
                  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @bender, may I know where should I place the .table-style in the code?

Comment: Hey,

your CSS goes either in a css-file (which is e.g. called style.css) and is linked in the head-section of your HTML file or you can place your css directly in the head-section of the HTML file.

The former is cleaner. I normally use first the latter version and when things get complicated/huge switch to the cleaner version with CSS code in a different file.

Here's a description of how to implement CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props='min-width: 60px;'),])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now set the col_space argument of [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html). col_space specifies the min width of all the columns.

```
df.to_html(col_space='75px')
```