# How to change width of cells, columns in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have columns:

```
df.columns = ['Nume', 'Tip de', 'Unit', 'Speciale Price', 'Suma de', 'Suma']
```

How to set width for each column?

I tried this way:

```
def width_cells():
    return ['width: 400px']     

df.style.apply(width_cells)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by set width for column ?? please elaborate the question.

Comment: I mean set min width of cell or in general column width

Comment: Not sure if this link will help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580111/how-do-i-set-the-column-width-when-using-pandas-dataframe-to-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I expand the output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns)

Comment: I need to set min width for all columns

Comment: Is it possible?