# Python Pandas - How can I set "column label" width

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Spyder to read a CSV file with many columns. I would like to customize the width of column displayed in console.

I have tried to use set_option to set column width. It works for columns but doesn't work for column labels.

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth",5)
```

[snapshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhbw6.jpg)

for example the column label "New revision distributed" is still not displayed with"...".

Anybody know how to set the column label width?

Thanks

Comment: Use `pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth",5)` and try

Comment: Sorry I copied wrong code in the original question, I used pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth",5), which only change the width of column (maybe it is a limited to quantity of characters) but not label width not changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the column width when using pandas.DataFrame.to\_html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580111/how-do-i-set-the-column-width-when-using-pandas-dataframe-to-html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I expand the output display to see more columns of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/how-do-i-expand-the-output-display-to-see-more-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Actually they are not the same question. I am trying to set the column label width which display in Spyder's console, for a easier way to read the table.